# I need to find only the DB_NAME having maximum LAG_MIN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.collection_timestamp,
                round((a.value / 60),0) lag_min,
                substr(b.target_name,1,instr(b.target_name,'.',1,1)- 1) db_name
FROM sysman.mgmt_metrics_raw a,
     sysman.mgmt$agents_monitoring_targets b
WHERE a.metric_guid = '26372D42E0B05538E505F330D67E8CEA'
      AND round((a.value / 60),0) > 5
      AND a.target_guid = b.target_guid
      AND b.target_name LIKE '%opp%'
      AND a.collection_timestamp > SYSDATE - 1
ORDER BY a.collection_timestamp ASC;
```

Returns below output. But I need to find only the DB_NAME having maximum LAG_MIN. How can I do that?

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM    LAG_MIN DB_NAME
------------------- ---------- ----------
2019-03-31 08:27:29        488 opp449a
2019-03-31 08:29:33        105 opp447a
2019-03-31 08:32:29        493 opp449a
2019-03-31 08:34:32        110 opp447a
2019-03-31 08:37:29        498 opp449a
2019-03-31 08:39:33        115 opp447a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use current query as a CTE (I named it "temp"), then something like this might do the job:

```
WITH temp AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT a.collection_timestamp,
                   round((a.value / 60),0)lag_min,
                   substr(b.target_name,1,instr(b.target_name,'.',1,1)- 1)db_name
     FROM sysman.mgmt_metrics_raw a,
          sysman.mgmt$agents_monitoring_targets b
     WHERE a.metric_guid = '26372D42E0B05538E505F330D67E8CEA'
       AND round((a.value / 60),0)> 5
       AND a.target_guid = b.target_guid
       AND b.target_name LIKE '%opp%'
       AND a.collection_timestamp > SYSDATE - 1
  )
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE lag_min = (SELECT MAX(lag_min)
                 FROM temp
                );
```

Comment: This query doesn't help. It is displaying only one record as below.
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM    LAG_MIN DB_NAME
------------------- ---------- ----------
2019-03-31 08:27:29        488 opp449a

Whereas it should have displayed all the DB_NAME with maximum lag_min. Like Below.
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM    LAG_MIN DB_NAME
------------------- ---------- ----------
2019-03-31 08:37:29        498 opp449a
2019-03-31 08:39:33        115 opp447a

Please suggest.

Comment: Shouldn't be. It should return a row with the `MAX(lag_min)`, and - according to your sample data - it is 498. Did you re-run the SELECT itself, to check whether data has changed?